# Return an item in a list that has the highest similarity with a compared value (using SpaCy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, similarity

I have an assignment where I am building a function that will take in a movie description and will compare it to a list containing 10 other movie descriptions. Using spacy, I have gotten as far as being able to print the 10 values of similarity, as seen below:

in the function, 'x' will represent the variable for the movie description.

```
def movie_reccomendation(x):
    with open("movies.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file_read:
        lines = file_read.readlines()
        movie_list = []
        for sub in lines:
            movie_list.append(sub.replace("\n", ""))
        

    for token in x:
        token = nlp(token)
        for token_ in movie_list:
            token_ = nlp(token_)
            movie_similarity = token.similarity(token_)
            print(movie_similarity) # Prints the 10 similarity values
```

I then figure I should be able to use max() on movie similarity, take that value and call the corresponding place in the list of 10 movies and display the recommendation, but the first issue I ran into with using max was a TypeError indicating 'float' object is not iterable. I am lost from where I need to go here...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's not enough detail here to figure out exactly what is going wrong, but it does look like you should be using `doc.similarity` and not `token.similarity`.

Comment: @polm23, thanks for the response. Curious what else is required? The only other lines of code are importing SpaCy, classifying the NLP and and the variable that I am storing the description as represented by x. As mentioned, I don't know where I need to go from here to continue the function to pull only the highest rated value and display its associated value from the list. Last, this assignment is specifically on token.similarity so I can't use doc.similiarity

Comment: provide a sample text string instead of `movies.txt` and your expected result.